# Celery creates several instances of Task

Tags: python, django, celery, tweepy

I'm creating a task (by subclassing celery.task.Task) that creates a connection to Twitter's streaming API. For the Twitter API calls, I am using tweepy. As I've read from the celery-documentation, 'a task is not instantiated for every request, but is registered in the task registry as a global instance.' I was expecting that whenever I call apply_async (or delay) for the task, I will be accessing the task that was originally instantiated but that doesn't happen. Instead, a new instance of the custom task class is created. I need to be able to access the original custom task since this is the only way I can terminate the original connection created by the tweepy API call.

Here's some piece of code if this would help:

```
from celery import registry
from celery.task import Task

class FollowAllTwitterIDs(Task):
    def __init__(self):
        # requirements for creation of the customstream
        # goes here. The CustomStream class is a subclass
        # of tweepy.streaming.Stream class

        self._customstream = CustomStream(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def customstream(self):
        if self._customstream:
            # terminate existing connection to Twitter
            self._customstream.running = False
        self._customstream = CustomStream(*args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        self._to_follow_ids = function_that_gets_list_of_ids_to_be_followed()

        self.customstream.filter(follow=self._to_follow_ids, async=False)
follow_all_twitterids = registry.tasks[FollowAllTwitterIDs.name]
```

And for the Django view

```
def connect_to_twitter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        do_stuff_here()
        .
        .
        .

        follow_all_twitterids.apply_async(args=[], kwargs={})

     return
```

Any help would be appreciated. :D

EDIT:

For additional context for the question, the CustomStream object creates an httplib.HTTPSConnection instance whenever the filter() method is called. This connection needs to be closed whenever there is another attempt to create one. The connection is closed by setting customstream.running to False.

Answer (score 0):

The task should only be instantiated once, if you think it is not for some reason,
I suggest you add a

print("INSTANTIATE")
   import traceback
   traceback.print_stack()

to the `Task.__init__` method, so you could tell where this would be happening.

I think your task could be better expressed like this:

```
from celery.task import Task, task

class TwitterTask(Task):
    _stream = None
    abstract = True

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(TwitterTask, self).__call__(stream, *args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            if self._stream:
                self._stream.running = False

    @property
    def stream(self):
        if self._stream is None:
            self._stream = CustomStream()
        return self._stream

@task(base=TwitterTask)
def follow_all_ids():
    ids = get_list_of_ids_to_follow()
    follow_all_ids.stream.filter(follow=ids, async=false)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried implementing the above and was just wondering where is the celery.utils.cached_property used?

Comment: It was just added there by mistake :) I'll remove it